# AJAX PHP multiple responses

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax question for you all.
I want to return an array from an ajax call in php and then get the values from that array that I return for use with a jquery ajax call, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction for a tutorial?

I know there's a bunch of different encoding types for ajax responses (json and xml come to mind) but I don't know really what there use is. Right now all I do is echo what I have as a response to get some things displayed on my page, but I want to change my current implementation to use an array as the response rather than just simple text. Though I don't know where to start in looking at tutorials on how to do this.

Also, what is the point of using the encoding types if I can just echo my text out and get what I want? I guess I really don't see the point of the json type or xml if I can just echo for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning arrays, I think JSON is the best way to go.

Its actually really easy to do.

PHP:

```
$array=array();//this is my array

$array=json_encode($array);//encode the array to JSON format, so that jQuery can decode it.

echo $array;//print it on screen
```

Now use some jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://mysite.com/myphpscript.php', function(my_data){

//now, my_data is your array..

//so access it like this:

alert(my_data.keyname);//"keyname" is an array key of your array

});//end of ajax request
```

The *point* of encoding your array is so that jQuery can pick it up as an array (with the help of JSON), and not just standard text.

Comment: hmm. I tried using this but every time I do an alert(data.keyname) it is undefined? when i go into chromes xhr debugger though it is showing that the response is sending the whole array as should be expected though, I think I am just unable to get the text from it? should I be decoding the data or something?

Comment: ha my bad, ignore the other post. I had to decode the json array using jquery.decodeJSON and then do the access using the data.keyname format. good stuff though thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start off encoding types are there specifically to solve a problem such as the one you posed.  They are there to organize multiple bits of information in a response, so you can return an array, or list, or multiple rows from a database, etc.

Json is my personal favorite, because of how light it is on syntax.  To pass the array from the PHP to javascript with AJAX, you'd first encode your array to json (basically taking the PHP array object, and making a text representation of it).  You can do this using PHP's `json_encode()` function ([PHP.NET reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Next you'll need to fetch that somehow, I will recommend Jquery here, because of their built in functions.  Using Jquery, you would type something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: {"somedata":"somedata"},
  success: function (data)
  {
    alert(data);
  },
  dataType: "json" /*now jquery will parse the json for you*/
});
```

In this code the anonymous function in the success will be called when the Ajax has returned information.  Because Jquery is great, it'll already have parsed the json, and put it in the object data.  Now each array item you passed from your php will be accessible via `data.[ArrayKey]`.

Also, you had asked for a tutorial, here is one that seems to be pretty good: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.T8PGz9VYua8

Hope that helps explain it a little better, I can give you an example if you like.